# Диапазон яркости для пикселей 0-255 в emgu.cv image

Tags: c#, изображения, float, byte, emgucv

Есть объект Emgu.CV.Image<Emgu.CV.Structure.Gray, float> obj
Нужно получить значения яркости пикселей изображения 16*16. Некоторые из значений ниже получились больше 255.

```
float[,,] data = obj.Data;
```

Как можно получить диапазон 0-255? Или перевести в Emgu.CV.Image<Emgu.CV.Structure.Gray, byte>?

Answer (score 0):

Каждое значение поделить на три